# Qt Mode for Emacs

Tags: c++, qt, emacs, indentation, dot-emacs

What are you using to develop Qt code in Emacs, so that it's highlighted/indented properly?

[This page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/QtMode) explains an extension to CC mode, but it seems a little outdated. Since Qt is constantly evolving, is there a more up-to-date Qt mode available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That page makes it pretty clear that the standard cc-mode packaged with GNU Emacs is supporting Qt extensions now; just make sure your cc-mode is up to date and you should be all set.