# Emacs C++ indentation confused by Qt macros

Tags: qt, emacs, cc-mode

Qt macros like Q_OBJECT and signals are messing up Emacs' indentation of my C++ code. How do I get Emacs to recognize the Qt macros and indent my C++ code accordingly?

Emacs version: 23.3.1
CC mode version: 5.31.8

According to the [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/QtMode), my CC-mode should support Qt macros out of the box but that is not happening with me.

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144512/qt-mode-for-emacs) has been asked but no solution was provided.

Comment: Could you provide an specific example? A minimalistic piece of code where such bad indentation happens, for instance.

Comment: @juanleon I added a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666888/emacs-indenting-after-macro-in-c.  See also my answer to that thread involving `c-macro-names-with-semicolon` variable, make sure it contains all QT macros you intend to use.

Comment: @immerrr "C-h v c-mac TAB" yields "c-macro-start" as the sole completion. Also, I would not want to add customization to CC mode for something it claims to already do. I would rather "debug".

Comment: @wsaleem, highlighting slots, signals and other stuff DOES work in vanilla Emacs23 for me as advertised, there's probably a misguidance in wiki about what should be skipped, because zrgrep for "Q_" shows up nothing in cc-mode sources. And neither does Q_OBJECT highlighting work in vanilla Emacs24, so you may be looking in wrong direction.

Comment: @wsaleem, also, I'd strongly advise against "debugging" an old release of cc-mode and rather download a new one if you cannot afford upgrading Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Qt macros have been updated since this functionality was added to Emacs, so Emacs  is a little obsolete in that regard.

The way to fix it is to update the variable `c-macro-names-with-semicolon`.  Current value is:

```
("Q_OBJECT" "Q_PROPERTY" "Q_DECLARE" "Q_ENUMS")
```

It seems to me that at least Q_INTERFACES should be added to it (maybe you know of more macros, I have no experience with Qt).

The proper way to fix it is to add this to your config:

```
(defun qt-macros-update ()
  (setq c-macro-names-with-semicolon '("Q_OBJECT" "Q_PROPERTY"
                                       "Q_DECLARE" "Q_ENUMS" "Q_INTERFACES"))
  (c-make-macro-with-semi-re))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'qt-macros-update)
```

And then do `M-x report-emacs-bug` for emacs maintainers to update the code and fix the documentation for that variable (that seems to be obsolete, too)

**Update:**

This works with Emacs 24.  with Emacs 23 I am afraid that this won't work.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to install Emacs 24 has opened up a [new can of worms](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377642/error-installing-emcas-24-on-ubuntu-12-04). I will come back to our problem once the Emacs install completes successfully.